# Add oninput attribute to HTML element with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I add oninput to an html `<input>` element with javascript?

```js
newinput.oninput = 'foo();';
```

This does not work - is there a way to do this?

Comment: A proper way: `newinput.addEventListener('input', foo);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('my_input').addEventListener("input", function () {
  console.log('input happened!');
});
```

```html
<input id="my_input">
```